# SQL: List the products ordered on a Monday

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to query products that were ordered on a Monday and I am confused on how to format or extract the specific day-of-week to the `orderDate` Value...

Here's what I have.. (I am fairly new to SQL, so I am probably way off.. )

```
SELECT Products.productName, OrderDetails.orderNumber, Orders.orderDate

FROM Orders, OrderDetails, Products

WHERE Orders.orderDate LIKE '%Monday%;
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `FROM Orders, OrderDetails, Products` ... this is doing an unrestrained cross join between the three tables, and it's probably not what you intended.  Have you heard of joining tables before?

Comment: Can you please tell us the datatype of column `Orders.orderDate`?

Comment: the datatype for column Orders.orderDate is datetime

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT  Products.productName , 
        OrderDetails.orderNumber , 
        DATENAME(dw,Orders.orderDate),  
        Orders.orderDate  
FROM Orders 
inner join OrderDetails  
   on OrderDetails.OrderID = Orders.ID 
inner join Products 
   on Products.ID = Orders.ProductID  
WHERE DATENAME(dw,Orders.orderDate) = 'Monday'
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT 
   Products.
   productName, 
   OrderDetails.orderNumber, 
   Orders.orderDate
FROM 
Orders 
JOIN OrderDetails ON Orders.OrdersID = OrderDetails.OrderID
JOIN Products ON OrderDetail.ProductID = Products.ProductID
WHERE 
DATENAME(DW,Orders.orderDate) = 'Monday'
```

Answer (score 1):

Use Datepart function, DATEPART(W,[DATE]) will return week day. (1 as monday)

```
SELECT Products.productName, OrderDetails.orderNumber, Orders.orderDate

FROM Orders, OrderDetails, Products

WHERE DATEPART(w,Convert(Date,Orders.orderDate))=1
```

**NOTE : This will give result in Cartesian product. please do join these tables properly**

Answer (score 0):

You can use the sql date function:
`Oracle: to_char(Orders.orderDate,'D')`
`MySql: DAYOFWEEK(Orders.orderDate)`